# Trying to apply the styles to a lead generator form in my WP blog post pages

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, css-selectors

I was asked by my manager to create a mechanism for lead generation by adding a form in all of our blog posts offering the visitor to receive that article in a PDF version by submitting their email address in a form located in the body of the text content of the blog post.

So I embedded the code for the form into the text file of the article, that form comes with styles that in the original version are not looking nice in the article, so I needed to style the form via CSS to make it look a little bit better.

After I style the form I will need to use selectors to style the form embedded into the post. Since the form has changeable IDs, I must use selectors that "begin with" so I can select them by the first part of the ID.

I have 2 problems here, one is with styling the form the way I need it to look, and the other is globally applying those changes to the form because I will add it to all blog posts.

Here's the link to the article with the form - https://www.treasy.com.br/blog/modelo-gecon/ (the form is at the end of the post with gray blocks and a green submit button)

I worked with a programmer and he styled it using inspector, although he was able to style it using the inspector he did not document those changes so I was not able to replicate those styles he placed. Here's how I wanted that form to look like: https://www9.online-convert.com/dl/web1/download-file/d5f5806e-e36d-4ced-af8c-d694c2e55bdc/imagem.webp

Here´s what the programmer sent me as "documentation" of the styles he placed (but like I said, I can't re-apply those styles):

```
#conversion-baixe-este-artigo-em-pdf-d254cfca8ed02e7333bb
.wrapper
element.style {
    width: 35em !important;
    text-align: center !important;
}

Sem tempo para ler agora? Baixe este artigo em PDF para ler mais tarde.
<h1>
{
    padding-top: 1em !important;
}

<section> Contem o email e botão baixar PDF
{
    width: auto !important;
}

#conversion-form-baixe-este-artigo-em-pdf-d254cfca8ed02e7333bb
<form>
{
    text-align: center !important;
    width: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: .5em !important;
}

Div do Campo de Email
.field
<div>
{
    display: inline-block !important;
    min-width: 23em !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}



Div do Botão Baixar PDF
.actions
<div>
{
    display: inline-block !important;
}

#I tried to create selectos to place the styles to modify the form in the header of the global settings of my site, but not all styles applied, I don't have experience with it and not sure what is wrong, but here it is:

lucas.bittencurt [3:54 PM]
div[id^="baixe-este-artigo-em-pdf"] {
   width: 35em !important;
   text-align: center !important;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding-top: 1em;
}


#conversion-baixe-este-artigo-em-pdf-d254cfca8ed02e7333bb section div.field, #conversion-modal-baixe-este-artigo-em-pdf-d254cfca8ed02e7333bb .modal-content section form div.field {
   display: inline-block !important;
   width: 69% !important;
}

div[id^="baixe-este-artigo-em-pdf"] actions {
   display: inline-block !important;
   width: 30% !important;
}
div[id^="baixe-este-artigo-em-pdf"] field {
   display: inline-block !important;
   width: 69% !important;
}
div[id^="baixe-este-artigo-em-pdf"] actions > call_button {
   padding: 6px 0 6px 0 !important;
   margin: 0!important;
}

form[id^="conversion-form-baixe-este-artigo-em-pdf"] header {
   padding: 10px 0px 0px 0!important;
   margin: 0 !important;
   background-color: #dbdbdb !important;
}
form[id^="conversion-form-baixe-este-artigo-em-pdf"] section {
  padding: 6px 20px 20px 20px!important;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO Lucas! Do you have the HTML of the form to post here? Also, what do you mean by "After I style the form I will need to use selectors to style the form embedded into the post. Since the form has changeable IDs, I must use selectors that "begin with" so I can select them by the first part of the ID."?

Comment: Thank you Bruno! That form is made by RD, a Brazilian CRM platform. The only thing available is the embedding code, no HTML.
Because this form is an embedded code into my blog post, I need to style it globally so that the changes I apply to it affect it in all blog posts. In order for me to do that I need to place selectors to find the elements of that form and style them by using a "beggins with" CSS selector.

Comment: Hey  Bruno, I just wanted to check if you got the answers to your questions and was able to understand them. I'm not very technical so I just wanted to make sure I covered all your questions.